# Domino Designer - Import Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Good day! How can I import an excel spreadsheet to Domino Designer? Will it require lotus scripting? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to import the data from a spreadsheet into a Lotus Notes database so that users can work with it? Or are you trying to import the layout and formulas from a spreadsheet in order to create a new application in Domino Designer?

Comment: I am trying to import data from a spreadsheet.

Comment: you can import csv- files using a col- file without even one line of code, or you can write an importer using LotusScript and Designer Client... Your question is way to broad like it is... We don't deliver solutions for general questions but rather help with concrete problems when you already started to code your solution...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time operation, then it's a simple matter to save the spreadsheet in CSV format and use the Notes client's import capabilities as mentioned by Torsten. If it's something that has to be done frequently, then you can write code. [Karl-Henry Martinsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207647/karl-henry-martinsson) has a blog post with some sample code in it [here](http://blog.texasswede.com/import-csv-from-excel-into-notes-documents/), which you can use to help get you started. Again, though, that example code also deals with CSV files, not .xls or .xlsx files. If your source of Excel data can't or won't give you a CSV, then you're going to have to work with Excel APIs (or write your own code to deal with the XML inside the .xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding).

```
xlFilename = "C:\myExcel.xls"
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open xlFilename
Set sheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Worksheets(1)
```

Reading content of an Excel cell:

```
sheet.Cells( row , column ).Value
```

Link: http://mattwhite.me/blog/2005/3/27/ole-lotusscript-class-to-read-and-write-to-excel.html